# How can I mock a local final variable

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

There a local variable in my method which is final. How can I mock?

```
public void method(){
  final int i=myService.getNumber();
}
```

I want to mock

```
when(myService.getNumber()).thenReturn(1);
```

How can I complete it with mocking?

My project is using Java 7, is there way using reflection or something else to realize this mock

Comment: You already know how to mock the `getNumber()` method. What exactly is the problem? Don't you know how to inject `myService` into the object under test? The final local variable seems not to be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This request, as stated, doesn't make much sense. Mocking systems don't mock variables (or fields). You could, however, easily set a field to an *object* you have mocked. Your test would look like this:

```
@Test public void methodWithNumberOne {
  MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
  when(myService.getNumber()).thenReturn(1);

  // You might want to set MyService with a constructor argument, instead.
  SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest();
  systemUnderTest.myService = myService;

  systemUnderTest.method();
}
```

---

Another way to set it up that doesn't require mocks:

```
public void method() {
  method(myService.getNumber());
}

/** Use this for testing, to set i to an arbitrary number. */
void method(final int i) {
  // ...
}
```